# C# Selenium неправильно работает для Edge

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Итак, проблема в том, что при запуске кода ниже открывается новое окно браузера, но тут же выдаёт ошибку:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: "unknown error: MSEdge failed to start: exited normally.
> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
> (The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so MSEdgeDriver is assuming that MSEdge has crashed.)"

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
namespace OC_University_Learning
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
      edgeOptions.UseChromium = true;
      edgeOptions.UseWebView = true;
      edgeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
      EdgeDriver edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(@"D:\Studying\Projects of language\OC_University_Learning\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1", edgeOptions);
    }
  }
}
```

При этом командная строка выдаёт:

> Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations
> for suggestions on keeping MSEdgeDriver safe. MSEdgeDriver was started
> successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Окей, проблема была в том, что последняя версия драйвера, что скачивается автоматически - 94, а последняя версия браузера 93, поэтому и возникало некое "недопонимание" между ними. Проблема решалась удалением msedgedriver.exe в решение/bin/ и замену его на версию драйвера 93, что я скачал с официального сайта Microsoft Edge(Standalone версия)